# How to import fbx image to an existing project

Tags: import

I have a 'project' consisting of a number of smaller objects which will eventually be integrated into a single object. I have found a great 3D (fbx) object and when I import it I have noticed that when I drag it around over my existing objects it appears on top of some and behind others.
How do I 'mark' this imported object so that appears 'above all my existing objects? See following screen shot (imported object is the car tire/tyre)where the tire is hidden by the large object but not by the smaller ones. I eventually want to use the tire in an array to be added to the edge face of the large object. Also I can use the 'rotate' tool to orient the tire to face 90 degrees from where it currently is but what is the method to 'snap' it 90 degrees rather than try and manually do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two questions, but I will answer both.

First, your description sounded like you are thinking of the tire as a 2D rendering of a 3D object, being moved about in a 2D space. It is in a 3D space. If you already understood that, I am sorry. But anyway, to fake it and make the tire render in front of everything all the time even if it is positionally behind it, you can use the render engine specific solution, or a permanent one that works with all engines. I will describe the latter.

1. Place the tire in its own collection, and place everything else except the lights and camera in their own collection together.
2. Create a new View Layer.
3. In that new layer, uncheck the collection without the tire.
4. If you do not want the tire to cast shadows on anything, uncheck its collection from the first view layer.
5. In Properties editor -> Rendering tab -> Film panel, enable Transparent.
6. In the Compositing screen, enable Use Nodes, then add both view layers, and use Alpha Over to put the tire over the other view layer.

About the rotation transform question, look at the top of the 3D view for a magnet icon. Check that the setting next to it is “Increment” and not something like “Vertex,” and enable Rotation and Scale (Location is enabled by default). Then, click the magnet to turn on snapping. Rotation will now snap to 5 degree increments.

Comment: Thanks. What had me puzzled was that the tire will appear in front of all my objects except one, the largest one regardless where I place the other objects.  Something else I have learned.  Also thanks for advising about the 'increment' setting.   I first started using Blender (and a 3D modelling application of any type) just 6 days ago and have learned a lot mostly from people at this 'forum' like yourself. Maybe I should invest in the purchase of Blender For Idiots (book) although the latest edition is for v2.8 and I use 2.92 as I hate reading documents on screen?

Comment: @JohnArnold well, there is an ePub version of the manual, which could then be put on an Amazon Kindle, which has a non-emissive screen kind of like an old calculator. But anyway…

Comment: @JohnArnold Just to clarify, the tire is not an image. It is 3D, and by the looks of it, it is vertically under the table along with those beams, which it actually intersects.

Comment: @JohnArnold try dragging your mouse around with the middle button pressed (usually hidden in the scroll wheel: press that down).

Comment: @JohnArnold I’m thinking of deleting my answer since it sounds like the first half is not what you needed.

Comment: Thanks Zacgui. On reflection I was starting to think that some of the objects had been moved on the Z axis and so other objects like the imported tire would pass under (or over).  PROBLEM is how can I snap an object back to the original plane (x, y and z) as well as not have it rotated? I can of course delete the object and recreate it.

Comment: @JohnArnold that’s yet another question, and should probably be asked separately, although I will answer it if you do.

Comment: Thanks again. I have now learned that the imported object was disappearing behind some objects and not others because many objects were on a different 'plane' eg Z axis. I discovered this when I was 'assembling' all my objects together and viewed them along a different axis. Wow I have learned a lot in the last week. My model is now complete.